# How to access Enum types in Django templates

Tags: python, django, enums, django-templates

I was having an issue where no matter what I did I couldn't access an IntEnum (from the enum34 lib) in my Django template.

I was able to get around it by converting it to a dict:

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super(MyView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    # Django templates don't play nice with Enums
    context['DEMOS'] = {d.name: d for d in DEMOS}
    # `context['DEMOS'] = DEMOS` doesn't work
    return context
```

These don't work when DEMO is an IntEnum, but do when DEMO is converted to a dict:

```
{{ DEMO.FOO }}  # outputs nothing
{{ DEMO.FOO|default_if_none:'foo' }}  # outputs nothing
{{ DEMO.FOO.value }}  # outputs nothing
{% if DEMO.FOO == 1 %}  # no matter what I compare to, always False
```

Any ideas why? Is this a known issue?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

A little more digging and I found the answer.

From [Django's templates documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/templates/):

> Technically, when the template system encounters a dot, it tries the following lookups, in this order:
>
> Dictionary lookup
>
> Attribute or method lookup
>
> Numeric index lookup
>
> If the resulting value is callable, it is called with no arguments. The result of the call becomes the template value.

That last line should say:

> If any of the resulting/intermediate values is callable, ...

Stepping through that process:

- lookup `'DEMOS'` in the `context`, get `<enum 'DEMOS'>`
- check if it is callable (it is)
- call it with no arguments
- get a `TypeError`

So the problem is that an `Enum` class is callable, and the templating system will try to call it, which will raise an error and abort (returning an empty string: `''`).

However, there is a way around that problem.
`django.templates.base`'s calling code contains the following
guard condition:

```python
if getattr(current, 'do_not_call_in_templates', False):
    pass
```

The code checks for an attribute called `do_not_call_in_templates`, and if `True` then it will skip the call portion, which should solve the problem.

Using Python's `Enum` (or the [`enum34` backport](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/enum34)) the simplest way will be to use a decorator.  If Django doesn't already have one for this purpose, you can roll your own easily enough:

```python
def forDjango(cls):
    cls.do_not_call_in_templates = True
    return cls
```

and then decorate your `Enum`:

```python
@forDjango
class DEMOS(Enum):
    eggs = 'runny'
    spam = 'hard'
    cheese = 'smelly'
```

The additional attribute does not interfere with your set of
Enum constants, because Enums are fixed once defined.

Comment: @EthanFurman What if you want to `DEMOS.eggs.name` ?  It seems that Django tries to call with the next `.` ?

Comment: Never mind to previous question, it works as expected.  Thanks for the answer.

Comment: I have my enum class inside my model class. Comparing in the template my state variable with <model>.<enum class>.<enum item> did not work but comparing it with the item's integer worked. (Django 4.2)

Answer (score 12):

Using Django's `Enum` you can use `__members__` property:

```
context['DEMOS'] = DEMOS.__members__
```

[Reference](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html#iteration)